# Two dynamic libraries, one in C other in C++, using eachother

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

Hoi,

I have a dynamic library loader, which is written in C++ but provides a C-compatible API.

That loader can load modules, which are written in any programming language. They're arranged in a named list and can request function pointers of other modules. Now, a module written in C and compiled with a C compiler gets the *functions pointers* of any other module, which is written and compiled in C++.

So my question: Are function-pointers cross-compiler valid? I think I heard of something like `__cdecl` once, long time ago. I use Linux 64bit.

T.I.A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// my C++ code ...
extern "C" {
  void thisFunctionWillBeCallableFromC();
}

void butThisOneMayNot();

struct S
{
    void thisDefinitelyWontBeCallableFromC(std::map<int, S>);
};
```

C++ code should declare interfaces with `extern "C"` linkage to be callable from C.

Or do you mean C++ code generated by different compilers?

Comment: Aw, good point. I use the GCC of course, but the project's a bit weird so there'll be any kind of compiler. That's a seperate question but how do I standardize that kind of stuff?

Comment: Use only C or `extern "C"` public interfaces and you're good. IIRC x86_64 has a well-defined ABI for C++ ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI_convention)), so unless one of your compilers is broken it _should_ still be ok - I just can't guarantee it.

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers are compatible between C and C++.

The only limitation, is that you have to declare your C-functions with extern "C" linkage when used within C++:

```
extern "C"
{
     int foo();
}
```

Comment: But why. I only get a function-pointer. The names are not resolved upon linkage. =P

Comment: function pointer layout is part of the ABI, which is usually standardized on your platform (unless you setup is weird).